# Select element but not certain inner elements in CSS

Tags: css

If I have this HTML

```
<p class="all">Example <span class="but">text</span> here.</p>
```

is it possible to write a simple CSS style to color the words `Example` and `here.` to red but leave the `text` to default color?

Comment: I'm assuming you don't want to explicitly set the color?  I don't think this is possible in CSS alone.  You will probably have to override the span's color with whatever the default color is.

Comment: Either override the `but` class, or use the `:not()` selector. Actually, after thinking about it, I think overriding the `but` class may be your only option.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **color:initial** property in css.

check the given below code snippet.

```css
p{color:red}
.but{color:initial;}
```

```html
<div>
  <p class="all">Example <span class="but">text</span> here.</p>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

not:- set a color for the span class but only

```
<style>
    .all{ color:red;}
    :not(but)({color:initial;}
    </style>

<p class="all">Example <span class="but">text</span> here.</p>
```